# how to convert binary to string?

Tags: string, text, binary

I saw there's a binary:

`0x22302e3130332e3020286537373133386520323032322d30342d31312920346436393665363536343432373935363639363134323534343322`

could be convert to text:

`UTF-8: "0.103.0 (e77138e 2022-04-11) 4d696e65644279566961425443"`

how is this done?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it, this is the convertion from 'hex string' to 'utf-8 string',
so the solution is:

step1. remove `0x` from the hex string,

step2.

```
a = "0x22302e3130332e3020286537373133386520323032322d30342d31312920346436393665363536343432373935363639363134323534343322".gsub('0x', '')
```

step3.

```
[a].pack 'H*'

#=> "0.103.0 (e77138e 2022-04-11) 4d696e65644279566961425443"
```